# How to move an element to the position where the user has clicked?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game and I want to move an element (which would actually be the character) to wherever I click on the page. (mousedown actually)

I believe it's possible with a script that changes an element's position on mousedown but I don't know how to do it.

I need a simple working example and then I'll figure out how to adapt it to my site but I haven't been able to find one.

I tried some simple moving, and found out a tutorial on how to move it with the keyboard but it's not quite what I want and couldn't find how to do it with the mouse.

I'm testing it here, though I'm chaning the code fast and most of the time nothing is working:
http://chusmix.com/game/movechar.php

Some advice, code, link anything will be welcomed. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: no, nothing at all. actually I experimented with moving stuff around with absolute position but I don't know how to combine that with clicking. I'm testing at: www.chusmix.com/game/movechar.php

Comment: Hint: `event.pageX` and `event.pageY`

Comment: I know it's cliche... but try JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to pull it off only with javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showCoords(evt){
  document.getElementById("character").style.left = evt.pageX;
  document.getElementById("character").style.top = evt.pageY;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onmousedown="showCoords(event)">
<div id="character" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; width: 80px; height: 40px; background:black;"> Char </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for all answers

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

HTML:

```
<div id="area">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/80/80" id="character">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var area = $('#area')[0];
    character = $('#character')[0];

$(area).click(function(e) {
    if ( e.target !== this ) { return; }
    var charWidth = $(character).width(),
        max = $(this).width() - charWidth,
        x = e.offsetX - charWidth/2,
        y = e.offsetY - charWidth/2;
    $(character).css({
        left: x < 0 ? 0 : x > max ? max : x,
        top: y < 0 ? 0 : y > max ? max : y
    });  
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/WUjKM/2/show/

Btw, I know it's jQuery `:/`. If you require a non-jQuery solution, let me know, and I'll rewrite it.